# Cassandra - WHERE clause range/token clerifications

Tags: jquery, cassandra, token, where-clause

I'm trying to understand how to perform a full range queries using Cassandra and to clarify some uncertainty regarding token usage based on [this](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) article.

Lets say that I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE space.rocket (
    id timeuuid, 
    group text,
    priority smallint, 
    date text, // Will hold YYYY-MM-DD
    PRIMARY KEY ((group , date) , priority, id));
```

What is the best option to have a range where clause?

---

For example:

Can I perform a range on group, date and priority, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM space.rocket
    WHERE token(group, date) => token('group-name', '2017-17-09')
    AND token(group, date) < token('group-name', '2017-17-10')
    AND priority >= (0) AND priority <= (10) # or priority IN (0,1,2...10)
```

Or I should use a token, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM space.rocket
    WHERE token(group, date, priority) => token('group-name', '2017-17-09', 0)
    AND token(group, date, priority) < token('group-name', '2017-17-10', 11)
```

And how about a query that will also include a range on secondary index (id), like this:

```
SELECT * FROM space.rocket
    WHERE token(group, date, priority, id) => token('group-name', '2017-17-09', 0, timeuuidStart)
    AND token(group, date, priority, id) < token('group-name', '2017-17-10', 11, timeuuidFinish)
```

Or, how to query for a list of groups and a range of dates?

---

Please advise,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**You should only perform token range query only on partition key**

In your case, partition key is `"(group , date)"`. So only your first query is correct.

```
SELECT * FROM space.rocket
    WHERE token(group, date) => token('group-name', '2017-17-09')
    AND token(group, date) < token('group-name', '2017-17-10')
    AND priority >= (0) AND priority <= (10) # or priority IN (0,1,2...10)
```

**Note : If you are using ByteOrderedPartitioner only then you will get meaningful result (data between 2017-17-09 and 2017-17-10). You should nevertheless be careful. Using a ByteOrderedPartitioner is not recommended as it can result in unbalanced clusters**

Learn More : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useToken.html

Comment: If I'm **NOT** Using ByteOrderedPartitioner, What are the consequences?
The query will return correct correct results (by where conditions) just with wrong order? or there will be performance impact? Please advise, Thanks!

Comment: If you are not using ByteOrderedPartitioner then your query is meaning less, you will not get data between 2017-17-09 and 2017-17-10. Because token of some date outside of your date range could be inside the range token of date and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fetch the range of data that you want would be to fire an asynchronous query for each partition key that you want and merge the results on your application side.

Using an IN or a slice relation on a clustering column will not make a lot of difference.